# In R, How do I create a dataframe from a text file which splits the data?

Tags: r, import

In R I am attempting to import a massive text file with the following structure:  This is an example saved as example.txt:

```
Curve Name: 
     Curve A
Curve Values:
     index   Variable 1   Variable 2
                   [°C]          [%]
     0               30          100
     1               40          95
     2               50          90
 Curve Color:
     Blue 

Curve Name: 
     Curve B
Curve Values:
     index   Variable 1   Variable 2
                   [°C]          [%]
     0               30          100
     1               40          90
     2               50          80
 Curve Color:
     Green
```

So far I can extract the names and colors

```
file.text <- readLines("example.txt")

curve.names <- trimws(file.text[which(regexpr('Curve Name:', file.text) > 0) + 1])
curve.colors <- trimws(file.text[which(regexpr('Curve Color:', file.text) > 0) + 1])
```

How do I create a dataframe with curve.name as a factor, and the other values as numeric in the following structure?

```
curve.name   index   variable.1   variable.2 
   Curve A   0               30          100
   Curve A   1               40           95
   Curve A   2               50           90
   Curve B   0               30          100
   Curve B   1               40           90
   Curve B   2               50           80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally a lot of `grep`. Finding a way to group entries, like the cumulative sum of a blank line, can be handy as well:

```
l <- readLines(textConnection('Curve Name: 
     Curve A
Curve Values:
     index   Variable 1   Variable 2
                   [°C]          [%]
     0               30          100
     1               40          95
     2               50          90
 Curve Color:
     Blue 

Curve Name: 
     Curve B
Curve Values:
     index   Variable 1   Variable 2
                   [°C]          [%]
     0               30          100
     1               40          90
     2               50          80
 Curve Color:
     Green '))

do.call(rbind, 
        lapply(split(trimws(l), cumsum(l == '')), function(x){
            data.frame(
                curve = x[grep('Curve Name:', x) + 1], 
                read.table(text = paste(x[(grep('index', x) + 2):(grep('Curve Color:', x) - 1)], 
                                        collapse = '\n'), 
                           col.names = c('index', 'variable.1', 'varible.2')))}))
##       curve index variable.1 varible.2
## 0.1 Curve A     0         30       100
## 0.2 Curve A     1         40        95
## 0.3 Curve A     2         50        90
## 1.1 Curve B     0         30       100
## 1.2 Curve B     1         40        90
## 1.3 Curve B     2         50        80
```

Comment: I up-voted all the answers; however, this one was selected because it handles variable length curves without additional packages.   The cumulative sum of the lines reading "Curve Values:" worked for the issue I had.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that every file has exactly the format from above:

```
txt <- readLines("example.txt")
curve_name <- rep(trimws(txt[c(2,13)]), each=3)
curve_color <- rep(trimws(txt[c(10,21)]), each=3)
val <- read.table(text=paste(txt[c(6:8, 17:19)], collapse = "\n"))
colnames(val) <- c("index", "var1", "var2")
cbind(curve_name, curve_color, val)
```

If the format is not exactly the above one, you can try to figure out the line-indices via the header's. So looking where it says `Curve Values:`

Which gives:

```
  curve_name curve_color index var1 var2
1    Curve A        Blue     0   30  100
2    Curve B        Blue     1   40   95
3    Curve A        Blue     2   50   90
4    Curve B       Green     0   30  100
5    Curve A       Green     1   40   90
6    Curve B       Green     2   50   80
```

Answer (score 3):

Slightly different approach assuming predictable formatting. We get each "record", extract salient components and bind them all together.

```
library(purrr)
library(stringi)

starts <- which(grepl("Curve Name:", lines)) # find the start of each record
ends <- which(grepl("Curve Color:", lines))+1  # find the end of each record

map2_df(starts, ends, function(start, end) {

  rec <- paste0(lines[start:(end)], collapse="\n") # extract the record

  # regex extract each set of values
  stri_match_first_regex(rec, c("Curve Name:[[:space:]]+([[:alnum:][:blank:]]+)",
                                "Curve Values:[[:space:]]+([[:print:][:space:]]+)Curve",
                                "Curve Color:[[:space:]]+([[:alnum:][:blank:]]+)"))[,2] %>%  
    trimws() -> found

    df <- read.table(text=found[2], skip=2, col.names=c("index", "variable.1", "variable.2"))
    df$curve.name <- found[1]
    df$color <- found[3]
    df

})
##   index variable.1 variable.2 curve.name color
## 1     0         30        100    Curve A  Blue
## 2     1         40         95    Curve A  Blue
## 3     2         50         90    Curve A  Blue
## 4     0         30        100    Curve B Green
## 5     1         40         90    Curve B Green
## 6     2         50         80    Curve B Green
```

Comment: Nice solution. @hrbrmstr why do you use `trimws` over `stringi::stri_trim_both`?

Comment: I shall blame it on typing brevity at 23:30EST :-)

Answer (score 2):

Read the lines into `L` removing any spaces before `Curve Color`.  (Removing spaces may not be necessarty if there are no spaces before `Curve Color` in the actual file but in the question there is a space before `Curve Color`.)  Then re-read the lines that start with a digit creating the `variables` data.frame.  Then read the `rest` using `read.dcf` and put the two together using `cbind`.

We have assumed that

1. Curve Values comes second so we can omit it from `rest` using `[, -2]`
2. Only lines in the numeric tables start with numbers (prefaced by whitespace).
3. Each numeric record has 3 columns with the column names shown in the question.  The rows start with an index number of 0 and subsequent rows in the same record do not also have a 0 `index` number. (There is no restriction on the number of rows in each numeric table and different records may have different numbers of such rows.)

No packages are used.

```
L <- sub("^ *Curve Color", "Curve Color", readLines("example.txt"))
variables <- read.table(text = grep("^\\d", trimws(L), value = TRUE), 
 col.names = c("index", "variable.1", "variable.2"))
rest <- trimws(read.dcf(textConnection(L))[, -2])
cbind(rest[cumsum(variables$index == 0), ], variables)
```

giving:

```
  Curve Name Curve Color index variable.1 variable.2
1    Curve A        Blue     0         30        100
2    Curve A        Blue     1         40         95
3    Curve A        Blue     2         50         90
4    Curve B       Green     0         30        100
5    Curve B       Green     1         40         90
6    Curve B       Green     2         50         80
```

Comment: Based on comment by poster that different records could represent different numbers of rows in the numeric table, have modified the code to allow this.  Also some simplification so the code is no longer than before.